# Make backButton in UINavigationController pop back to rootViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a UINavigationController with a rootViewController (A) a second ViewController which is pushed from that (B) and third viewController that is pushed from the second (C). When the user presses back from the third viewController (C) I want it to automatically pop back to the rootViewController (A), I am struggling to find a way to do this effectively.

Push A -> B -> C
Pop A <- C (skipping B)

Thank you!

Comment: In C,`self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`

Comment: Do you want your navigation stack to pop to the root view controller specifically on the pressing of the back button?

Comment: You can get all viewcontrollers pushed and by checking the class name you can pop back to required view controller. 

Example code :-

NSArray *arrayOfViewContrller = [appDelegate.navigationController viewControllers];
        
        for(int i= 0 ; i<arrayOfViewContrller.count ; i++)
        {
            if([[arrayOfViewContrller objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[AViewController class]])
            {
                [appDelegate.navigationController popToViewController:[arrayOfViewContrller objectAtIndex:j] animated:YES];
                return;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can get all viewcontrollers pushed and by checking the class name you can pop back to required view controller. 
Example code :-

```
NSArray *arrayOfViewContrller = [appDelegate.navigationController viewControllers];
for(int i= 0 ; i<arrayOfViewContrller.count ; i++)
{
    if([[arrayOfViewContrller objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[AViewController class]])
    {
        [appDelegate.navigationController popToViewController:[arrayOfViewContrller objectAtIndex:j] animated:YES]; return;
    } 
}
```